# Community blog for Money.stackexchange

Tags: discussion

Quite a few stackexchange communities have their own blog. See the list here http://stackexchange.com/blogs. Currently Personal Finance does not have its own dedicated blog.

The proposal is to have a community blog for Personal Finance & Money as well. There are quite a few good answers here that can be created as a blog post that are more detailed. Essentially consolidate our knowledge and wisdom under various topics.

Anyone else would like similar place to consolidate the knowledge?
Please upvote the question if you like this idea.

Edit:
- The Blog can be someone spending time to collate good detailed answers and create / edit it as a blog post.
- Create new content on topics not asked here as back ground, for example basics of economics
- New Posts some tax question that's not yet asked or anything on interest in Personal Finance.

Comment: Many users here are already bloggers.  Understandably I don't think they want to blog here as well.  I would highly encourage you to look at our user list and follow some of them on their personal blogs.  You are right; there is good stuff out there.

Comment: We're not opposed to it, but we'd need to be sure some of the established users would keep up with it. A blog can be a great addition as long as it doesn't just sit, and has a decent representation of the community writing for it.

Comment: Not sure I understand the proposal. What would the *blog* offer vs the 5k+ Q&A we have here? Raj said 'consolodate,' I think there might be value in a format that lists titles on a given topic, say for Roth, a list of the links to the top Q&A. In effect, a page that let's one browse without searching. Is that the proposal?

Comment: I think Raj is asking about http://stackexchange.com/blogs ... we have our own money.blogoverflow.com and keep good atricles there for ready reference.

Comment: I see the main blog, but not one specific to Money. Can you link?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Sorry wasn't clear in my earlier comment, other communities have bolg, we currently don't have one. Raj is asking should we have one. This was discussed earler in stackoverflow. Any community can have its own blog provided there is sufficient people contributing and sustaining it ...

Comment: Reading http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26681/learning-investment-books-to-read-fundamental-value-motley-fool - It seems we have multiple 'book list' Q&A. Would a blog post consolidating these lists be of value? I'm thinking of a method of categorizing books by sub-topic so anyone can see what their goals are and choose the right reading sub-list. Thoughts?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Agreed. We can start with categorization of books.

Answer (score 4):

Yes We should have the dedicated blog area.

I will be reading it, but will not be contributing [or contributing less than once per week]

Please upvote this if you like the idea of blog.

Comment: With my limited knowledge, I will try to contribute.

Comment: I am neutral on this proposal until I understand its purpose. If someone would like to fill in the blank, the blog would have posts that _______. I like the Q&A format in the mail area. I have a day job, a blog, and freelance writing. No time to donate more writing. Happy to read what others write....

Comment: @Dheer - In response to your note at other answer - I'd participate, less than once/wk. Not new material so much, but a couple summary articles. "An over view of credit scoring" that would link here to the multiple Q&A on the topic, with a bit of discussion to fill in the gaps. So +1 to this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes We should have the dedicated blog area.

I would actively contribute one Post a week.

Please upvote this only if you will be contributing.

Comment: To all, note the subtle difference on this question: up-voting here would imply you will regularly submit a post.

Comment: The proposal suggests "There are quite a few good answers here that can be created as a blog post that are more detailed." Is this really the case? The are question here whose answers are quite detailed. On the other hand, I'm looking at other sites that offer a blog area, such as the home improvement site, and see only a few posts this year. Circling back - is the blog intended to be a re-written 'best of' or new material people wish to donate here absent a question?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Both